# Regex check character before new line is not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to replace new line characters (\n) with html 
 tag's. But this should not happen if the line ends with an another html tag.

Like this:

```
Line 1<br />
Line 2<br />
<p>Hello World</p>\n
Line 4<br />
```

So my question now is why isn't the following regex working? Now are on every line 
 tags not just on the lines without the <\p> tag.

```
/(?!<.*>)\n/g
```

That regex is working if I dont want to have a <\br> tag if the next line doesnt contain html tags.

```
/\n(?!.*<.*>)/g
```

Comment: Which programming language/tool are you using?

Comment: I'm jusing javascript. The problem is that those functions simply replace '\n' with '<br />' and I you can read in my question I just want to set a br tag if the line doesn't end with a html tag.

Comment: So, like '<tag><tag>some text `here-> \n` <tag><tag>' is what you want to match ?

Comment: Your pattern isn't working because that is a negative _lookahead_ pattern - it says if at the point I match a `\n` I don't see `<.*>` then I am good. You need a lookbehind pattern but unfortunately they are not supported by Javascript yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some logic with the following expression here:

```
.+<[^\n\r]+>$|(.+)
```

In `JavaScript`:

```js
var html = `Line 1
Line 2
<p>Hello World</p>
Line 4`;

var converted = html.replace(/.+<[^\n\r>]+>$|(.+)/gm, function(match, group1) {
    if (typeof(group1) == "undefined") return match;
    else return group1 + "<br>";
});
console.log(converted);
```

The idea is to **match** lines ending with a potential tag but to **capture** those without, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/VJAotX/2).